# How to sort lines by regex with sed

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to sort lines in file by matching regex in column2 (ending TLD) using `sed`.

This is an example file:

```
server7, server.com,someval
server6, server.com, someval
server4, server.uk, someval
server2, server.com, someval
server10, server.us, someval
server7, server.uk, someval
server10, server.uk, someval
server10, server.us, someval
```

I've tried with:

```
sed -r "s/(.*\.com.*)|(.*\.uk.*)|(.*\.us.*)/\3\2\1/g" file
```

But that reproduce the same output, making no changes.

I want my file to be sorted like:

```
server7, server.com,someval
server6, server.com, someval
server2, server.com, someval
server10, server.us, someval
server7, server.uk, someval
server10, server.uk, someval
server10, server.us, someval
server10, server.us, someval
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: You seem open to using different tools. Can you use the tool "sort"?

Comment: In short - do you want `sort` by the TLD?

Comment: Yes @jm666 . I can do something like `awk -F "," '{if($2 ~ /\.com/) print} {if($2 ~ /\.us/)print}print' file` but I don't think it is a right..

Comment: `sort -t. -k2 file` - will sort the above by the TLD. (the `.` is a separator)

Comment: Doing a trick as well. :) @jm666 Feel free to post the answer!

Comment: pretty simple job for `sort` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use the `.` as a field separator, you can sort the file, like:

```
sort -t. -k2,2 file
```

The above (of course) needs to have same number of `.` dots in the line (at least in the first 2 columns).

As @mklement0 said in the edit: using `-k2,2` instead of the plain `-k2` is better because:

> it's cleaner (more robust, more efficient) to limit sorting to the
>   field of interest - if you don't specify an end field, everything
>   *through the end of the line* is sorted